# Forms(Android: )How to correctly instantiate native HttpClient to use in shared project

Tags: xamarin.forms

I don't know hot to correctly instantiate the native Android HttpClient for my shared Xamarin.Forms project. I have done reading and searching.

The questions:
1. How do I make sure, that my Android client will use the native HttpClient for all kinds of network transfer even for actions defined in the shared code?
2. Do I have to instantiate a HttpClient in the Project.Android project part of the code and inject the object into the Project.App() constructor like Project.App(HttpClient httpClient) or does that function automatically by some kind of build-time magic?
3. Currently my code would be fine with a HttpClient built by its default Constructor, but can I have constructor parameters when instantiating native HttpClient?

- I tryied to instantiate HttpClient() in the Android project, but couldn't do it: its not known in the namespaces, Assembly
- I put a breakpoint on the point on the shared Xamarin.Forms project where HttpClient gets instantiated, it seems to be the System.Net.Http HttpClient. So the managed Client I suppose...

Current code snipets and settings:
- Scope: Xamarin.Forms Android
- architectures: armeaby-v7a;arm64-v8a (have x86 in separate configuration, that works much better)
- HttpClient implementation: Android
- SSL/TLS implementation: Default (Native TLS 1.2+)
- Xamarin.Forms 4.1.0.581479
- SDK: NETStandard 2.0.3

Project.Android MainActivity.cs:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.OS;

public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);            
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
```

My HttpClient instantiation in the shared project:
basically creates the object with default constructor when first needed and reuses it for every operation

```
private static Lazy httpClient = new Lazy(
() =>
{
var client = new HttpClient();
return client;
});
```

Comment: If you want to use httpclient in share project, firstly, reference shared project in Android project, then add system.Net.Http library to Android project, you can use HttpClient

Answer (score 1):

The ultimate purpose of Android - SSL/TLS implementation to improve performance so i whould like to suggest you use NuGet package **modernhttpclient**.
Replace below line in your code

```
   private static Lazy httpClient = new Lazy(() =>
     {   
      var client = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
      return client;
     });
```

using **NativeMessageHandler** you can handle both Android and iOS,

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

In the meantime I have used the following two lines in the Android MainActivity() to inject the HttpClient object into the shared project:

            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler());

            LoadApplication(new App(httpClient));

Is your NativeMessageHandler defaulting to Xamarin.Android.Net.AndroidClientHandler on Android platforms?